# obtener un valor del 1 al 5 con estrellas e imprimirlo en un input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

necesito ayuda no tengo mucho conocimiento en javascript.
debo obtener un valor del 1 al 5 con estrellas e imprimirlo en un input.
El codigo que tengo funciona bien solo que nose como hacer que me imprima el valor en un input.

Lo que busco es imprimir el valor que obtengo de **"rating__result"** e imprimirlo en un

Intenté de esta forma:
const ratingResult = document.querySelector("input[name='stars']");

pero no funciono.
Necesito que el resultado se imprima en un input para luego guardarlo con el metodo POST

```js
const ratingStars = [...document.getElementsByClassName("rating__star")];
const ratingResult = document.querySelector(".rating__result");

printRatingResult(ratingResult);

function executeRating(stars, result) {
   const starClassActive = "rating__star fas fa-star";
   const starClassUnactive = "rating__star far fa-star";
   const starsLength = stars.length;
   let i;
   stars.map((star) => {
      star.onclick = () => {
         i = stars.indexOf(star);

         if (star.className.indexOf(starClassUnactive) !== -1) {
            printRatingResult(result, i + 1);
            for (i; i >= 0; --i) stars[i].className = starClassActive;
         } else {
            printRatingResult(result, i);
            for (i; i < starsLength; ++i) stars[i].className = starClassUnactive;
         }
      };
   });
}

function printRatingResult(result, num = 0) {
   result.textContent = `${num}/5`;
}

executeRating(ratingStars, ratingResult);
```

```css
@import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css";
body {
   height: 100vh;
   display: grid;
   place-items: center;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.rating {
   position: relative;
   width: 180px;
   background: transparent;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   gap: .3em;
   padding: 5px;
   overflow: hidden;
   border-radius: 20px;
   box-shadow: 0 0 2px #b3acac;
}

.rating__result {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   transform: translateY(-10px) translateX(-5px);
   z-index: -9;
   font: 3em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   color: #ebebeb8e;
   pointer-events: none;
}

.rating__star {
   font-size: 1.3em;
   cursor: pointer;
   color: #dabd18b2;
   transition: filter linear .3s;
}

.rating__star:hover {
   filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 4px gold);
}
```

```html
<div class="rating">
        
          <span class="rating__result"></span> 
         <i class="rating__star far fa-star"></i>
         <i class="rating__star far fa-star"></i>
         <i class="rating__star far fa-star"></i>
         <i class="rating__star far fa-star"></i>
         <i class="rating__star far fa-star"></i>
      </div>
   
      
     // Imprimir resultado en input
       <input name="stars" value="0" type="number" class="rating__result"> 
       
       <hr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya casi lo tenias, tan solo debes efectuar este cambio.

Donde pones esto:

```
result.textContent = `${num}/5`;
```

cámbialo por esto:

```
result.value = num;
```

porque es un `input` y el atributo que contiene lo que ves es el `value`.

`textContent` en este caso incluiría texto como nodo hijo pero no como `value`.

Aparte de eso, lo que decias con esto:

```
const ratingResult = document.querySelector("input[name='stars']");
```

también funciona ahora que ya hemos puesto el `value`.